# How to open an exe minimized while passing a parameter using batch?

Tags: batch-file

Although I know how to start an exe minimized and launch an exe with parameters separately, I cannot figure out how to do both at once.

For minimizing the window, I did:

```
start /min "name.exe"
```

And for passing parameters:

```
"name.exe" "param1 param2"
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33512469/edit) to include what you've tried. It sounds like you're really close.

Comment: What does this have to do with python and vbscript.  Those tags do not seem to apply to this question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought vbs might be needed to do this, and I guess python was just irrelevant. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using command **start** you can execute an application minimized and specify all the parameters you want if the application does not restore its main window automatically to last saved size or even shows its main window always maximized. So if this approach works depends on the started application.

```
start "Running ..." /min "Path to Application\ApplicationName.exe" "First Parameter" SecondParameter /Option1 /Option2
```

Note: The first double quoted string is interpreted as title which is the reason why a title should be always specified on using command **start**. It can be also an empty string, i.e. `""` instead of `"Running ..."`. An empty title string makes most often sense on starting a GUI application.

For details on command **start**, open a command prompt window, execute `start /?` and read the output help.